# 56 bit encryption in iPhone app to avoid export limitations by BIS

Tags: iphone, xcode, encryption, des

I need a push in the right direction - preferably with code samples/links - for how to encrypt an NSString using DES encryption algorithm. Knowing that it is not that secure, but a possible candidate for avoiding to file a CCATS.
Could commoncrypt be the solution?
Or would using the key chain or sqlcypher be able to provide encryption and avoid the CCATS paper work.

In my app, i dont see any issue with 56 bit security and i dont assume any issue with a symmetric key solution.

In short: 
I can't find any good example of how to use **56bit DES symmetric** encryption for my ios 4.2 app (This is to avoid the CCATS hassle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Security.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: Can you confirm that using this would provide me of a way not to deal with the CCTAS hassle? And could you provide me with some code? I cant find any good code lines for symmetric Security.framework usage.

Comment: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

Comment: I've read the discussion blog you are pointing at, but two things: The first comment pretend that using an NSData category could sidestep the CCTAS. I can't see how and why and can't get an answer from its author. Secondly, there must be a more recent discussion/example than july 2009. Which i obviously just cant get my hands on.

Comment: I think the point is that you'd be using Apple's encryption code, and they already filed the papers for it. But I'm not a lawyer. I think it's "CCATS", btw.